# kannel status denied in playSMS

Tags: sms-gateway, ubuntu-server, kannel

I'm trying to use playSMS on ubuntu Server 14.04.
I've installed playSMS like show [here](https://sites.google.com/site/elinguiuriel/playsms-kannel/installation-playsms) and I've configurated Kannel like show [here](https://sites.google.com/site/elinguiuriel/playsms-kannel/passerelles-sms/playsms-kannel).
My /etc/Kannel/kannel.conf is:

```
# CORE
group = core
admin-port = 13000
admin-password = playsms
status-password = playsms
log-file = /var/log/kannel/kannel.log
log-level = 0
access-log = /var/log/kannel/access.log
smsbox-port = 13001
store-type = file
store-file = /var/log/kannel/kannel.store
smsbox-max-pending = 100

# SMSBOX
group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = localhost
bearerbox-port = 13001
sendsms-port = 13131
sendsms-chars = "0123456789+"
log-file = /var/log/kannel/smsbox.log
log-level = 0
global-sender = "isi dengan sms center"
access-log = /var/log/kannel/access.log

#SMSC MODEM GSM
group = smsc
smsc = at
port = 13013
host = localhost
smsc-id = modex
modemtype = auto
device = /dev/ttyUSB0
sms-center = "+393359609600"
speed = 230400

# GROUP MODEM
group = modems
id = siemens_mc35i
name = "SIEMENS MC35i"
detect-string = "SIEMENS"
detect-string2 = "MC35i"
init-string = "AT+CNMI=1,2,0,1,1"
speed = 230400
enable-hwhs = "AT\\Q3"
need-sleep = true

# SENDSMS-USER
group = sendsms-user
default-smsc = default
username = playsms
password = playsms
max-messages = 10
concatenation = true

# SMS SERVICE 'default'
group = sms-service
keyword = default
accept-x-kannel-headers = true
max-messages = 0
assume-plain-text = true
catch-all = true
get-url = "http://localhost/playsms/index.php?app=call&cat=gateway&plugin=kannel&access=geturl&t=%t&q=%q&a=%a&Q=%Q"
```

But when I login in playsms application my sms go into queque and I can see they in Outgoing SMS with yellow box.

If i go to Administration -> Manage gateway -> Kannel -> Manage kannel, the kannel status is denied.

Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your Kannel is running, you can do ps ax and tail Kannel log to see whether or not the Kannel runs properly.

`ps ax | grep box
tail -f /var/log/kannel/kannel.log`

once you know that Kannel is running then login to your playSMS web, through menu: Administration -> Manage gateway -> Kannel -> Manage kannel, you need to set Kannel admin port and Kannel admin password, which according to your kannel.conf they are:

admin-port = 13000
admin-password = playsms

Answer (score 0):

try to check this link url of kannel status in the browser : 
there is the link :
http://localhost:13000/status?password=playsms